# ".htaccess" doesn't work for cache-control at sub directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control

I made my own `cache-control` rule in `httpd.conf`. ANd need to apply different rules on each different sub directories.

I made `no-cache` for `.do` extension for default(`httpd.conf`).

```
# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess

...


    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      <LocationMatch "\.(do)$">
        Header append Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      </LocationMatch>
    </ifModule>
```

And need to cache for some directories(`.htaccess`).

example URL : `XXX.com/en/product.do`

So I made a `.htaccess` on `<webRoot>/en`.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <LocationMatch "\.(do)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </LocationMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Am I going wrong? Is there other way to rule different on different directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like `<locationMatch>` can be used in `.htaccess`; it will generate a runtime error.

Also, usually `*.do` is proxied, in which case no filesystem directory would ever be read for `.htaccess`.

I suggest putting the second stanza first, and adding `^/en/` to the front.

Comment: Could you give me a sample please?